# Minecraft server lag since updating to 1.8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, performance

My server has worked well since 2011, however, nowadays, since updating to 1.8 (actually some subversion of 1.8, not actually 1.8, but I went directly from .2, 3 or something to .8) it lags very much.
This is an average message in my server log

```
[SERVER thread/WARN]: Can't keep up! Did the system time change, or is the server overloaded? Running x behind, skipping x tick(s)
```

The ticks can go up to 2000+ and 70000ms.

Now, you might think I have 60 plugins with 100 players but I'm running vanilla with max 3 players. I have allocated 2GBs of RAM.

Some of the problems I'm having is that everything is slow, I can travel and the terrain generates 1 minute later (unless I'm kicked with the reason "Timed Out"), or I might hit a monster and suddenly, 30 seconds later I am dead and the mob has walked 30 blocks away.

Comment: Check how much RAM and CPU the server is using. You could also upload the world file so we can check if it's anything in the world causing this. If it's hosted on your computer, try connection to localhost to see if it's a connection issue.

Comment: Maybe you need to upgrade your hardware,

Comment: Try generating a new world to see if it's an issue with your server or with something in the world.

Comment: @Erman Seems overkill, it has worked all the way up here with no lag whatsoever, I don't think this update would suddenly make me have to upgrade. The computers specs are way beyond the minimum.

Comment: @Silentvenom7 I tried generating a new world and I am seeing similar issues.

Comment: What Java arguments are you using?

Comment: @LittleHelper `#!/bin/bash; cd "\`dirname "$0"\`"; java -Xmx2048M -Xms1024 -jar craftbukkit.jar nogui` (It's named craftbukkit.jar even though it's vanilla, it started out as a bukkit server and I just rename every new jar file).

Comment: @EdwardRide Try using http://www.spigotmc.org/ which is a fork of Bukkit and has better performance than vanilla servers, that might fix your issue

Comment: You're using default arguments I had this problem too when running 1.8 servers with default arguments. I fixed by using these launch parameters: `-server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2 -XX:+AggressiveOpts nogui`. Not a single problem ever since.

Answer (score 3):

If the server is hosted by a external company, contact them about the server issues. This problem can also be created by your wifi speed, you may want to run a speedtest.net scan on your wifi to make sure nothing is wrong. Also, if you are the one hosting the server, try connection through localhost:(port) next time to possible reduce lag. And one last thing, you may want to check if its not just minecraft thats lagging, you could have too many things installed on your computer or too much RAM being used at the time. Also, you may want to consider lowering the RAM usage for 3 players, if you are only hosting a vanilla server, with few slots you DO NOT NEED 2GB, a bukkit server with 10-20 slots needs about 1 GB, so lower the RAM usage if your hosting and yeah! :)